# How to parse a json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am parsing the below json in php

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":22,
    "params":{
      "fl":"title,id",
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"einstein",
      "hl.simple.pre":"<em>",
      "hl.simple.post":"</em>",
      "wt":"json",
      "hl":"true",
      "rows":"3"}},
  "response":{"numFound":63,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "title":"Albert Einstein"},
      {
        "id":"2088",
        "title":"Nationalism"},
      {
        "id":"1551",
        "title":"Dean Koontz"}]
  },
  "highlighting":{
    "1":{
      "text":[" for school exam September The Collected Papers of Albert <em>Einstein</em> Vol Doc s Unthinking for authority"]},
    "2088":{
      "text":[" in a letter to Alfred Kneser June Doc in The Collected Papers of Albert <em>Einstein</em> Vol Nationalism"]},
    "1551":{
      "text":[" changes since meeting Travis Did you get the leash on him yet <em>Einstein</em> Part Chapter Nora s query during"]}}}
```

using json_decode and looping through the result array I could get the individual elements in the docs section,

```
foreach ($myArray['response']['docs'] as $doc) {
        echo $doc['id'] . "<br/>";
        echo $doc['title'] . "<br/>";
    }
```

I am now trying to figure out in getting the values from the highlighting section of this json. I want to get the text fields in the highlighting part and store it in a array.

```
"highlighting":{
    "1":{
      "text":[" for school exam September The Collected Papers of Albert <em>Einstein</em> Vol Doc s Unthinking for authority"]},
    "2088":{
      "text":[" in a letter to Alfred Kneser June Doc in The Collected Papers of Albert <em>Einstein</em> Vol Nationalism"]},
    "1551":{
      "text":[" changes since meeting Travis Did you get the leash on him yet <em>Einstein</em> Part Chapter Nora s query during"]}}}
```

The array should be like this,

```
"1" => " for school exam September The Collected Papers of Albert <em>Einstein</em> Vol Doc s Unthinking for authority"

"2088" => " in a letter to Alfred Kneser June Doc in The Collected Papers of Albert <em>Einstein</em> Vol Nationalism"
```

How to achieve this? Is there any way to map the id element of the docs to the number specified in the highlighting part?

Comment: Just reassign the value to the new key. It will look something like `$x['hilighting']['1'] = $x['hilighting']['1']['text']`. Do this in a loop for each key in "hilighting".

Comment: Instead of giving you the answer, I'd suggest you try something on your own first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this ([Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3Fv7TA))

```
$myArray  = json_decode($json, true);
$highlighting = array();
foreach($myArray['highlighting'] as $key => $value)
{
    $highlighting[$key] = $value['text'][0];
}
```

**Result :**

```
Array (
    [1] =>  for school exam September...
    [2088] =>  in a letter to Alfred ...
    [1551] =>  changes since meeting ...
)
```